# No MediaQuery ancestor could be found?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a Container that is a third of size of the page but i'm getting an error `No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().` and I'm not sure why at all. Its in `MaterialApp`.

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(LoginPage());

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
              )
            ],
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try something like this..```void main() => runApp(MaterialApp (home:LoginPage()));```not sure if it works.. just give it a try..

Comment: IT WORKED! can you elaborate on why this worked? i have MaterialApp in build function so why would i get this error?

Comment: I did, check my answer @STOPIMACODER

Comment: @STOPIAMACODER, Glad it worked for you.. kindly accept my answer..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to give the `MaterialApp` as the ancestor..as the error says..

Do it like this..

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home:LoginPage()));
```

Answer (score 5):

Your must have a `MaterialApp` widget because you are using the `Material` class from your `import statement`

Check the code below, it works fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// wrap your LoginPage widget with a MaterialApp widget
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home:LoginPage()));

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
              )
            ],
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me. It was because the `showModalBottomSheet` tries to access the ancestor of type `MaterialApp` from the given context.

Use `Builder` widget to get new context with `MaterialApp` ancestor

**OR**

Separate your `MaterialAapp` and `Scaffold` widgets into separate widgets.

My solution using `Builder` :

```
floatingActionButton: Builder(
  builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () { showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Text('Modal bottom sheet', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30));
          });
      }
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

to add to this, there are cases where the generated test case is not updated to match your current main class [image]