# Got a stack frame from package:stack_trace, where a vm or web frame was expected

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-web

I am using the `web (Chrome)` to run my application. But, I get an error. Here is the error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
Assertion failed:
file:///Users/name/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart:192:7
line != '===== asynchronous gap ==========================='
"Got a stack frame from package:stack_trace, where a vm or web frame was expected. This can happen
if FlutterError.demangleStackTrace was not set in an environment that propagates non-standard stack
traces to the framework, such as during tests."

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp
  MaterialApp:file:///Users/name/development/projects/flutter/hello_world/lib/src/hello_world.dart:12:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed
packages/flutter/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart 192:15                           fromStackTraceLine
dart-sdk/lib/internal/iterable.dart 391:20                                        moveNext
dart-sdk/lib/internal/iterable.dart 869:20                                        moveNext
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 748:20  next
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 586:14                of
dart-sdk/lib/core/iterable.dart 470:12                                            toList
packages/flutter/src/foundation/stack_frame.dart 87:37                            fromStackString
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1066:54                           defaultStackFilter
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1260:43                           _applyStackFilter
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1235:17                           new
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 725:22                            debugFillProperties
packages/flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart 2992:17                          <fn>
packages/flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart 2994:16                          get builder
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1285:56                           get builder
packages/flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart 3009:105                         getProperties
packages/flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart 1244:62                          [_debugRender]
packages/flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart 1121:14                          render
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1013:44                           dumpErrorToConsole
packages/app/main.dart 28:69                                                   <fn>
packages/flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart 1177:14                           reportError
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6408:16                               _debugReportException
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4815:9                                performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6350:36                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6362:32                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4968:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                               performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4787:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6215:14                               mount
```

This error only occurs when running my app using `web (Chrome)`. If I use `Android Emulator` I don't get this error.

I referred to some posts like [Widget test fails with No MediaQuery widget found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48498709/16124033), [No MediaQuery widget ancestor found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68635405/16124033), [No MediaQuery ancestor could be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61969143/16124033) and other posts but still can't resolve this error.

Some code snippets:

`main.dart`:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
…

Future<void> main() async {
  await runZonedGuarded(
    () async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.path);
      runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MaterialApp(home: HelloWorld())));
      …
    },
    (Object error, StackTrace stack) {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
      debugPrint(stack.toString());
    },
  );
}
```

`hello_world.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:hello_world/src/app.dart';
…

class HelloWorld extends StatelessWidget {
  const HelloWorld({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        theme: …,
        home: const App(),
      );
}
```

`app.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
…

class App extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends ConsumerState<App> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    kIsWeb ? null : …;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    …

    return Scaffold(
      body: …,
    );
  }
}
```

I am not very sure whether the error is derived from this line:

```
runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MaterialApp(home: HelloWorld())));
```

How can I fix this error? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include a codesnippet that causes the issue

Comment: I recommend creating a reproducible example and filing an issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I solved this error by setting `FlutterError.demangleStackTrace`:

```dart
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart' as stack_trace;
```

---

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const HelloWorld());
  FlutterError.demangleStackTrace = (StackTrace stack) {
    if (stack is stack_trace.Trace) return stack.vmTrace;
    if (stack is stack_trace.Chain) return stack.toTrace().vmTrace;
    return stack;
  };
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting this?

Comment: @Abushawish `void main()`

Comment: what's causing this?

Comment: @DeanVillamia sorry, I don't understand. What does "this" mean?

Comment: ahh the error itself, what's the root cause of it~ or any github thing I can checkout hehehe

Comment: @DeanVillamia My understanding is some packages create a different format of stack trace to those produced by the VM, maybe via `package:stack_trace`  (Riverpod uses it for example). But Flutter expects to parse normal VM stack traces, so it lets us set  `FlutterError.demangleStackTrace` to perform a custom conversion back to a VM stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine had a similar error and that was due to an empty string given to a network image.
I can see in your stacktrace there is an error thrown in `iterable.dart` > `moveNext`. So it makes me think that your issue is caused by an invalid loop or something similar.

Comment: I don't think there is invalid loop in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and did these things and it worked.

1. Use the [`demangleStackTrace`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/FlutterError/demangleStackTrace.html) function
2. Run the `flutter clean` command in the terminal, then upgrade the Firebase dependencies to the new version.